# Log UIControlEventAllTouchEvents Name

Tags: objective-c, nslog

I have a UITextField to which i have added an action for all kind events

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(log:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];
```

Now in log: method I would like output event name

```
- (void)log:(id)sender {
 NSLog(@"%@",event);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(log:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];
```

use:

```
[textField addTarget:self action:@selector(log:event:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventAllTouchEvents];
```

and implement the action method with two arguments: `(id)sender` and `(UIEvent *)event`:

```
- (void)log:(id)sender event:(UIEvent *)event
```

Comment: This seems to work most of the time, but not always. Sometimes I get the sender object as the event. Is this documented by Apple anywhere?

Comment: Which kind of UIControls make it unpredictable ?